# Struct function doesn't work with my array

Tags: c

So I basically have a struct with a name, which has to be dinamically, and an ID. I think it can look like this.

```
typedef struct {
char *name;
unsigned int id;
} person;
```

Now I shall write a function with the given start:

```
person *readData();
```

Both the struct and the name have to be dinamically, I want to do this with the malloc function. For all persons there should also be an array, let's name it "people[1000]".

Here are is my try on the said function with the main function:

```
int count = 0;

person *readData() {
    int i, len;
    char puffer[1000];

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf_s("%999s", &puffer);

    len = strlen(puffer);
    people[count].name = (char *)malloc((len + 1)*sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        people[count].name[i] = puffer[i];

    people[count].name[len] = '\0';
}

void main(void)
{
    person *people[1000];
    readData();
    printf("\n%s\n", people[count].name);
}
```

Well, it doesn't seem to work that way. Visual Studio says in the function, that "people" has to be of type union or struct. 
Any quick input? It's just basic C since I am at the start of learning it.

EDIT: Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
char *name;
unsigned int id;

} person;

person people[1000];

int count = 0;

person *readData() {
int i, len;
char puffer[1000];
printf("Name: ");
scanf_s("%999s", &puffer);
len = strlen(puffer);
people[count].name = (char *)malloc((len + 1)*sizeof(char));
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    people[count].name[i] = puffer[i];
people[count].name[len] = '\0';


}

void main(void){
readData();
printf("\n%s\n", people[count].name);

}
```

Comment: Your array of pointers (`people`) is local to the `main()` function, so it's impossible for `readData()` to know about it without you passing it (or making it global). You probably didn't mean `person *readData()` but `void readData(person* people)`. Your code contains a lot of other problems too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`people` variable is undefined in the body of your `readData` function. 
That is why the complier fails with error.

1. You can pass variable to the function `person *readData(person *people)`. 
   Do not forget to change  `readData();` to `readData(people);` in the `main` function.
2. Do not mix pointer notation with array notation if you need just 1-dimensional array.
   Use `person people[1000];` instead of `person *people[1000];`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
Since I got this function without any parameters and I got others >with< parameters I suppose I shall do it without.
That's the main problem I currently have and that's why I wanted to make "person people[1000]" global.

Comment: Just declare your variable outside of `main` function body if you really want to do it.

Comment: Even with a parameter I still get the error in the struct function where I want to say "people[count].name". The error regarding count says that it has to be of type pointer-to-object.

Do you have an idea regarding that as well?

Comment: Did you consider my 2nd suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, I applied that as well.

Comment: It is difficult to figure it out without viewing at actual code.

Comment: Reformatted some stuff and now I just get a crash after I enter a name. I edited the full code in the main post.

Comment: Okay, seems that scanf_s has some problems with the used parameters. Now I took gets_s and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your function readData doesn't know about your people array. If you rewrite it along these lines:

```
void readData(person** people) {
    your code
}

void main() {
   person* people[100];
   readData(people);
}
```

It should go better.

Please see zavgs answer for more things to improve.

Comment: Any way to do it w/o parameters?

Comment: @user3177280 Not so easily. But what is the problem with parameters?